# phpQuery Evento Web Scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping

Estou querendo pegar informações do site da fipe utilizando phpQuery, porém ainda estou aprendendo a utilizar.

As informações que eu quero pegar aparecem em um `select` porém apenas após clicar nele. Sem clicar ele retorna apenas um `<option value=""></option>`

Gostaria se tem um pegar os valores com se tivesse clicado no `select` para aparecer outras opções.

```
<?php
require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

$pagina = 'http://veiculos.fipe.org.br/';

phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($pagina); // instanciando a classe com a variavel da url

echo '<h2>O conteudo do ID selectMarcacarro é</h2>';

$titleElement3 = pq('#selectMarcacarro'); // capturando elemento de ID deivison do documento test.html

echo '<p>' . htmlentities( $titleElement3->html() ) . '</p>'; // exibindo o resultado
```

Também, existe algum método fácil de se fazer web scraping?

Comment: Qual a utilidade ? É necessário ser em *PHP* ?